# Get name of selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am newbie to JavaScript / html , so my question may be silly for you but I am stuck on it.

I want name of selected check box. I have tried following code

```
<br>    
<%
for(int i = 0; i < dataDetail.size(); i++)
{
%>
<input type="checkbox" name="<%=dataDetail.get(i)%>" onclick="select(dataDetail.get(i))"> <%=dataDetail.get(i)%>
<br/>
<% 
} 
%>


<script type="text/javascript">
function select(a)
{   
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =a    
    }
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

But I there is no changes on the page, please help on this

**Edit**

[Link for my jsp page](http://pastebin.com/SaDKZPTs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the parameter inside quotes in onclick handler function. Also don't use function name as `select` which is a JavaScript reserved keyword. You can [check the reserved keyword list here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm). And use change event in case of checkbox.

```
<br>
<% for(int i=0 ; i < dataDetail.size(); i++) { %>
  <input type="checkbox" name="<%=dataDetail.get(i)%>" onchange="selectFn('<%=dataDetail.get(i)%>')">
  <!------------                 here                 ----------^-----------^-------------------->
  <%=dataDetail.get(i)%>
 <br/>
<% } %>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function selectFn(a) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a
  }
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: No any effect in output

Comment: @swapnil7 : can you share html rendered in browser

Comment: I have provided the link of my jsp

Comment: @swapnil7 : I mean, the rendered html output in browser

Comment: I don't get any error on browser , it doesn't reflect any changes on html page

Comment: @swapnil7 You can get the source code in browser(view page source option) share that html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113739/discussion-between-swapnil7-and-pranav-c-balan).

Comment: @swapnil7 : glad to help you :)